# NSJSONSerialization Failing

Tags: ios, json, swift, serialization, flickr

I am making a simple request to the Flickr API. I know that the request URL is correct and that the URL task returns data. However, when I try:

```
let jsonObject: AnyObject! = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: [])
```

in a do, catch block, the operation fails but doesn't crash the app. I have tried changing the options to MutableContainers and AllowFragments but nothing seems to work.

Comment: If you transform data to string with UTF8Encoding, does the string seems JSON and valid?

Comment: Yeah it is formatted correctly

Answer (score 1):

Take the data and convert it to a string like this:

```
let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

Then paste that through a validator like jsonlint.com to see if you're actually getting valid JSON.

I suspect you aren't getting a valid HTTP response from the API, and so maybe you're getting HTML back (or plain text) that describes the error?

Comment: I sent it through that and it said it was valid. However, when I print it out to the console, it shows up as jsonFlickrApi( valid data ). Is this normal, or is it what's throwing the error?

Comment: Can you post the code and the actual JSON you're seeing from the `NSData` encoding?

Comment: The responseString prints as:  Optional(jsonFlickrApi({"photos":{"page":1,"pages":10,"perpage":100,"total":1000,"photo":[{"id":"25954170134"......"width_h":"1600"}]},"stat":"ok"}))